# logback feature - how can I develop a listener for rolling events?

Tags: java, logback

I am looking for a listener for rolling events. State Listener is not good enough.

The listener I am looking for will enable users access to the rolling appender and will allow them to append logging events prior to any other event on the new file.

This will be similar to http://www.simonsite.org.uk/javadoc/org/apache/log4j/appender/FileRollEventListener.html developed by Simon Park for log4j.

Does anything similar exist today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a subclassed `RollingFileAppender` could be a workaround. I would try overwriting the [`setFile`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html#setFile%28java.lang.String%29) and/or the  [`rollover`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html#rollover%28%29) methods.

Comment: Overriding rollover and calling subappend directly works for me. Thanks;.